# jQuery.each and .html not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

I would expect this:

```
$('.iat_map').each(function(i,el) {
    $(el).html(opt_list);
});
```

And this:

```
$('.iat_map').html(opt_list);
```

To do the same thing. However, when I try the former, it clears the contents instead of replacing it with `opt_list`. (`.iat_map` refers to a bunch of `<selects>`).

If I `console.log(opt_list)` inside that `each()`, it ouputs as expected.

What gives?

[Made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/U9agP/1/). Perfectly reproducible (in Chrome 21 at least).

Comment: Could you put a fiddle? It would help.

Comment: @elclanrs: I'll try. There's some ajax involved.

Comment: @elclanrs: see update. link at bottom.

Comment: fairly certain i know what the issue is, i'm just working on the implementation. i think it's moving the entire list of elements during each iteration. it puts them inside the first select, then moves them to the second, and so forth, because they're references. i need to clone the list or something.

Comment: You know what may actually be going on here?  maybe the each loop method is using the same instance of opt_list, where the .html method is internally creating a new instance for each element.  trying to assign the same DOM element to a new parent would likely remove it from its previous parent.

Comment: @MikeC: Pretty sure that's exactly what's going on :-)

Comment: Yeah I see that answer now.  Im on a mobile phone so it takes forever to post a comment! :)  nothing better than simply repeating something someone else already said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `opt_list` is a jQuery object (meaning jQuery made the options into DOM elements), and when you append jQuery object, the DOM elements are removed from their old spot and added to their new spot.

That's why when you use `.each`, you'll notice that the options are only on the last select.

Apparently, when you do `$('.iat_map').html(opt_list);`, jQuery clones the DOM elements before appending them.

I suggest making `opt_list` into a string, instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: Yup. Just figured this out. I thought it was a reference issue, but I couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: @Mark: It took me a sec to realize it.  At first I was like "WTF?", but then I noticed the elements were only on the last select, and that made me go "AH HA!" :-)

Comment: You know what I just notice that we've been using a `for...in` to loop an array, I didn't see it in the original fiddle and I had the error too.

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell what's happening, tried a bunch of things that I thought could be causing trouble and couldn't find a solution so far but this is how I would do it and it works.

```
var options = [
    [1, "one"],
    [2, "two"],
    [3, "three"]
];

var list = [];
for (var i in options) {
    list.push(
        '<option value="'+ options[i][0] +'">'+
            options[i][1] +            
        '</option>'        
    );
}

$('.sel').empty().append(
    '<option>&ndash; Not selected &ndash;</option>'+
    list.join('')
);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/U9agP/4/

Comment: This is right, Mark messed up the correct building of the list.

Comment: I just added the default option that Op had in his question.

Comment: You know what may actually be going on here?  maybe the each loop method is using the same instance of opt_list, where the .html method is internally creating a new instance for each element.  trying to assign the same DOM element to a new parent would likely remove it from its previous parent.

Answer (score 1):

Needed the clone the list. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/U9agP/5/

It was moving the elements from one `<select>` to the next, because they're references.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery documentation,  the call to each for a jQuery object is slightly different from the call you use on a generic array.

Try losing the `el` and just use `this` instead.

```
$(this).html(opt_list);
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: According to the docs, `el` is the element, and "`this` refers to the element".  Therfore `el === this`.